# Copy file or folder via Groovy Script with custom name

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am trying to implement in my SoapUI project a groovy script that will copy certain files after the request is executed. I have checked other topics and I have managed to use one of these scripts:

```
class FileExample {
   static void main(String[] args) {
      def src = new File('C:/Users/USERNAME/Desktop/Results/Test_Result.xml')
      def dst = new File('C:/Users/USERNAME/Desktop/Groovy Scripts/Copied File/Test_Result.xml')
      dst << src.bytes
   }
}
```

The problem that I am facing is that the generated files are generated with a specific name that is not a constant and I can't give a constant name of the file that needs to be copied.

I have tried several methods to define this search, but all were unsuccessful. I have tried with:

```
def src = new File('C:/Users/USERNAME/Desktop/Results/', '**.zipx')
```

but it didn't work.

Can you tell me another method which I can use to point out the custom file that I want to copy?

Kind regards,

Kristiyan

Answer (score 2):

if you need only one file

```
def src = new File('C:/Users/USERNAME/Desktop/Results').listFiles().find{it.name.endsWith('.zipx')}
```

you can iterate through files using `eachFile`, `traverse`, or [other methods](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/io/File.html)

```
new File('C:/Users/USERNAME/Desktop/Results').eachFile{src->
    if(src.name.endsWith('.zipx')){
        def dst = new File('.../Copied File/', src.name)
        src.withInputStream{stream-> dst << stream }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That works perfectly :) Can also tell me if you know how I can define the file by a keyword that is before the extension. I have tried something like `if(src.name.endsWith('%Value%.zipx')` but it didn't work.

Sorry if the question is a bit stupid but I am new in this and not so fluent with all defining methods :/

Kind regards,
Kristiyan

Comment: I have also tried with `if(src.name.eachFileMatch(~/.zipx/))` but again received an error as a response ... perhaps I an not defining it like properly. My goal is to copy each file that contains the specific value in its name before the extension.

Comment: `if(src.name ~= /.*SomeKey.*\.xzip/)` where `/.*SomeKey.*\.xzip/` is a regular expression

Comment: I ha tried like this: `.eachFile{src->
    if(src.name ~= /.*SomeKey.*\.zipx/)` but I am still getting an error :( **column 17. if(src.name ~= /.*Pack.*\.zipx/) ^ org.codehaus.groovy.syntax.SyntaxException: expecting ')', found '~' @ line 2**. Perhaps I am not defining it correctly ...

Comment: sorry, that's should be `name =~ /.../`

Comment: Sorry, disregard the last comment :)

I didit like that `eachFile{src->
    if(src.name =~ /.*SomeKey.*\.zipx/)` and the magic worked :) It seems that I had to create a new Groovy step in SoapUI in order to make it work properly. Thank you very much one more time! You are a star!

Comment: That's fine. Thank you again very much :)

The last struggle that I am on is to give a defined field from my custom properties as a regular expression.I am writing it like this:

`def prop= context.expand('${#TestCase#prop}')

//.eachFile{src->
    if(src.name =~ /.*prop.*\.xml/)`

but the system counts the **prop** as the regular expression not the value that is written on the custom property which should be the exact value that I want to search with. It is generated after the SoapUI application is executed so each time is different. Any idea how to point it out?

Comment: instead of regexp quotes use string `src.name =~ ".*"+prop+".*\\.xml"` . note that in string you have to escape `\` -> `\\`. also if prop contains regexp-valued symbols (not just letters) you'll have unpredictable behavior. maybe better to use expression like this: `src.name.indexOf(prop)>0 && src.name.endsWith(".xml")`

Answer (score 1):

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils

FileUtils.copyFile(new File('/path/to/file1'), new File('/path/to/file2'))
FileUtils.copyDirectory(new File('/path/to/dir1'), new File('/path/to/dir2'))
```

Documentation of this Java package :

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html